# The completness of ring and its power series ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, power-series

> Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ an ideal of $R$. If $R$ is $I$-adically complete, why then $R[[x]]$ is $(IR[[x]]+(x)R[[x]])$-adically complete? (Matsumura, *Commutative Ring Theory*, Exercise 8.6.)

Take a Cauchy sequence $(a_n)$. By definition for any $k$ there exists $N$ s.t. $m,n\ge N$ then $a_m-a_n\in J^k\dots$

Comment: Have you tried picking a Cauchy sequence and seeing that it converges?

Comment: Yes,but I couldn't. And I have to show hausdorffness of R[[x]].

Comment: Why couldn't you? If you edit the question and provide details of what you tried to do, we might be able to help you carry it out. That will be, in the end, 5 times more useful than someone writing down some argument completely disconnected with what you were thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short calculation (whose steps can be justified by the reader):

$\lim_n R[[x]]/(I,x)^n = \lim_n R[[x]]/(I^n,x^n) = \lim_m \lim_n R[[x]]/(I^n,x^m)$
$= \lim_m \lim_n R/I^n[[x]]/(x^m) =\lim_m R[[x]]/(x^m) = R[[x]].$